Сложение и сортировка таблиц
Есть таблица reviews с столбцами:

Id, content,  isPositive, userid, contentID,

Таблица REVIEWS_REACTIONS с столбцами:

reviewsID ,user,  isPositive(boolean)

Нужен sql запрос который вернет таблицу 1 и доп. поле в котором указана разница положительных и отрицательных значений таблицы 2 в столбце isPoitive, с определенным значением contentID.

Чем вас принятый ответ на этот же вопрос не устроил?
